# index apache nutch result in solr

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, web-crawler, nutch

I wanna to crawl web site with Nutch and then index result in Solr.

I have in solr schema.xml file .that imagine in this file i have field content.

but every site has own pattern for example in some one i wanna to set "body" tag in "content filed(in solr schema)"
and for another site i wanna to set "content" in "content filed(in solr schema)".

I mean if in crawl result i find body tag i use this to store in content field,
else if i find body tag i use this value to store in schema file.

how can i do that?

can i set specialfield in solr fill based on multi Tag value in nutch crael result based on what tag it found in each web site?

Answer (score 0):

Indexing content with Nutch and posting to Solr should be straightforward. But if you want to add logic and the list of rules might grow, it might be recommended to use a content processing engine.

I've seen this tool used for that specific purpose but it uses Heritrix as crawler and you can create Groovy scripts to decide how to handle your content :www.searchtechnologies.com/aspire

Comment: thanks i found apache tika usefull. i see that i can write my own txt parser (in my case own html parser).so i have my own logic.and extract my own div id from html pages.so i can use nutch then tika and then index in solr